# Tick Checkbox on Webpage using VBA

Tags: vba

I am trying to automate one webpage based activity, where I need to select the Checkbox. There are multiple Checkbox available on the page and out of those, I need to select a particular one. I have tried many solutions provided on internet, but it gives me only one error as "object doesn't support this property or method". Below is the HTML code for the Checkbox. It would be really helpful if you revert with some VBA code to perform the Tick Checkbox action.

Also please let me know if any additional information is needed.

```html
<input class="check" submitname="chkPropLinkId" type="checkbox" value="120633"></input>
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer from different site. Below is the workable VBA code for the query,

```
Set elems = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("check")
For Each e In elems
    If (e.getAttribute("value") = "120633") Then
        e.Click
        Exit For
    End If
Next e
```